# Why HTTPS is faster then HTTP?

Tags: http, firefox, ssl, https

It makes me crazy.

I know that HTTP connections must be faster then HTTPS since we need some time for SSL handshaking and encoding / decoding data.

But I have checked two images from deviantart and from flickr and get same results.

Also I have checked results in Firefox network tab and in [HTTP Debugger Pro](http://www.httpdebugger.com) and got same results (I don't know why FF shows different sizes for same image).

Here is the test image with and without HTTPS:
http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/082/a/0/flying_jellyfish_wallpaper_by_andrework-d7bcloj.jpg
https://fc05.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/082/a/0/flying_jellyfish_wallpaper_by_andrework-d7bcloj.jpg

[image: Firefox Network Tab]

[image: HTTP Debugger]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a protocol, HTTPS is *not* faster than HTTP. Holding this claim<sup>3</sup>, then:

HTTPS might benefit from [QoS (Circumvention)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quality_of_service#Circumvention) on *your path*<sup>2</sup>. I get the *same* speed for both resources, which is to be expected<sup>1</sup>.

Alternatively, it could be another artifact on *your path* such as an HTTP proxy; or pretty much anything which *only* slows down the HTTP traffic.

I suspect *your path* is the issue because the same symptom - which is a significant time difference! - is seen when connecting to different servers.

---

<sup>1</sup> Any handshake overhead is dominated by the transfer time on a low-latency connection. Likewise, any encryption overhead is dominated by the network transfer speed.

<sup>2</sup> The particular network path taken from your browser to the server, whatever that is.

<sup>3</sup> This is a very *weak* claim (that is, I did not claim that HTTP was faster) and is not a difficult proposition to back up. If HTTPS traffic was fundamentally faster (much less twice as fast!), nobody would still be using HTTP.